# Software Critique: Open Source Software

Tags: language-agnostic, open-source

Where can I find critical analysis of OpenSource projects?

ie: in-depth analysis of methods within the source, a comparison of projects with others, and performance metrics ...

I'd like to read something about existing projects that would give me an overview of its design, implementation, strengths and weaknesses, so I can choose something to get involved in.  Hopefully, there would be more than one analyst per critique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ohloh](http://ohloh.net) will give you some information, but only what can be machine counted from source code repository data, i.e.:

- Languages used, how much of each
- Comment percentage
- Developer base (i.e. expanding over time)

However, I don't know of any service/site that does automated method analysis at the code level. Ohloh might eventually convey something like "Mostly OOP", but that would be in the distant future.

Almost all reports like the type you mention are done by hand, in a lab and testing a very targeted group .. i.e. comparing performance and coding methods of various web servers. Almost all of the time, you'll find these types of reports on the Slashdot front page, as its data that many people would be interested in seeing.

Something like Ohloh could give you a good start of what you would want to compare yourself, but I know of nothing that will do it for you with any degree of reliability.

Answer (score 2):

Patrick Smacchia (author of execellent tool NDepend) posts analysis of open source projects on [his blog](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/)

Some posts I remeber

[Lessons learned from the NUnit code base](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/)

[Analysis of Paint.NET](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/10/20/controlling-the-usage-of-libraries.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you do some searching around on [ohloh.net](http://www.ohloh.net/). While it doesn't offer a analysis of architecture, it gives a lot of useful statistics (language, activity, location of members, user rating, license type, news, etc) about popular open source projects. You may find this a useful tool in looking for a project to contribute to.

As an example, here is the page for NUnit: http://www.ohloh.net/p/nunit

You can always search open source project hosting sites such as [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/), [Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/), and [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) as well, although the information isn't as in depth as with ohloh.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem with open source software seems to be that there is no marketing department (usually) that makes the developers move in a more user - friendly direction.

Yeah, some Linux distributions look nice on the surface but the amount of half - finished, meh - code is incredible.

I have seen amazing stuff like unfinished text editors which gave a "feature not implemented yet" warning on every second click in some distributions, etc...

Answer (score -3):

Not trying to sounds offensive but your question is completely backward. You should be asking **what you can do for a specific open source project**. Why anyone would analyse open source projects and compare them against each other, I have no idea. I can see some benefit in looking at performance metrics for the **actual software** but this would be genre specific and in no terms general.

Your best bet is to go to sites like freshmeat, look at the release history, source code and developers working on projects that are of **specific interest to you** and ones **where you can make a difference**

In short:
**Software can be compared against other software**

**Projects cannot be compared against other projects**. And to do so is ill-informed. What is considered the *right* method by some is often seen as *wrong* by others.

Comment: I think you missed the point. Adequate critique is very useful and can help to learn on others faults rather then doing errors yourself

Comment: I think the OP just wants to get involved in one or more projects but is having a hard time finding one that matches his preferred methods, style and interest. Projects *can* be compared against other projects, for instance, project A might prefer a c-style that is closer to your own than project B.